# Unicode glyphs are not combining for indian languages in ImGui

Tags: unicode, unicode-string, imgui

In the ImGui project, words in indian languages are read from a json file where they are displayed properly. And when they are displayed in the window the glyphs are not combining.

Even when checked through UTF-8 encoding viewer of imgui metrics, they are not combining.

I have tried many fonts for each language but the results are the same
[image: examples for glyphs not combining]

Comment: From quick look on the documentation, I think they are not using nor implementing multi-language library nor a shaping library (shaping library is needed for "ligatures"). But the library is "*bloat-free*" so removing the very complex and buggy code.

Comment: Text shaping is not supported by the library as it was designed for quick debug tools and has little to not caching and very basic font system. It's unlikely this is going to be officially supported soon.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, so you mean that Imgui does not support language libraries other than those they provide by default. And there is no way to resolve this

Comment: @Omar by library do you mean ImGui does not support text shaping, and there is no way to resolve this issue

Comment: For the sake of simplicity let's pretend there's no way, no.